# Embed Angular App within another page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a javascript app which is called within another page I do not control. I'd like to be able to embed an Angular JS app, but how do I handle routing without modifying the URL? How would testing (ie. e2e) work in this scenario?

**Edit:** The app is a wordpress plugin which is overlayed on the Wordpress dashboard, therefore the URL and Page History cannot be modified. The app will be bound to a div which is embedded in the page, and overlayed on existing content using CSS.

Comment: If you don't control the page how are you going to "embed" it. And by "embed" do you mean "place in an iframe" or "put in a div on the actual page and load my app on that page"

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this as well. There are valid use cases...for instance, one company may write an app which should be embedded in another company's web site.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can just inquire AngularJS and your app, and using hooks to provide necessary HTML. A few things to note though:

- Because the URL cannot be changed, you should use router in legacy mode (using URL hash) instead of HTML5 mode.
- Since you're running in generated URL, the `templateURL`s must be built dynamically. 
  For example, ouput a script tag for URL to your plugin folder:

  ```
  <script>var MY_PLUGIN_BASE = '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>'</script>
  ```

  And then later define your route and `templateURL` using that constant:

  ```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: MY_PLUGIN_BASE+'my-plugin/views/main.html',
      controller: 'Main'
    })
  ```

  This works, but in general I will avoid using routes in such situations. This cause more work in the controllers and directives, but it is safer because there could be other client side MVC apps on the page.
- The `ng-app` is attached to the root element of your view instead of `body`.

---

For more general embedded AngularJS app (in my experience: a bookmarklet), you need to:

- Inject AngularJS if needed (check for `window.angular`), CSS and HTML.
- Inject your app's JS file. Because only one `ng-app` will be auto bootstraped, bootstrap your app manually using `angular.bootstrap`

  ```
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('my-app'), ['MyApp'])
  ```
- Use absolute URL for `templateURL`, and make sure that URL have CORS enabled.
- Again, avoid using routes if possible. For the Wordpress plugin, we're pretty sure that there's no other app using hash for routing (Wordpress is using Backbone, but I don't see the routes), but in general there are already a MVC app on the page that handle routing.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! We'd like to not have ANY URL changes (including hashed). There's an embedded flag in Ember that allows you to do this (routing is handled programmatically), I was hoping for the same in Angular (but then I don't know how links would work, because they seem to require a URL). Can you provide a small example of how I would emulate different views using just controllers and directives?

Comment: You can just use Angular-UI/UI-Router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. It is very similar to Angular's route, and the url is optional for all states. 

The way I was doing it before is having a function `linkTo(url)` on the `$rootScope` that change a `url` (also on the `$rootScope`), and the view is hide/show with `ngIf` based on the current `url`.

Comment: What about giving http://www.noembed.com/ a shot? I've been trying to get this up and running. This option wouldn't be specific to wordpress