# Building Angular App and embed on another page you didn't write

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

It is possible to build a JavaScript library, use JQuery and then embed it on another page.
[For example](http://dublintech.blogspot.ie/2012/12/a-javascript-quiz.html)...

You can import the library...

```
<link href="http://dublintech.github.com/JavaScript_Examples/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://dublintech.github.com/JavaScript_Examples/jsquiz/js/jQuiz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can then invoked a function from the library and even pass it a dom element

```
quizModule(quiz_questions, $('#intro'));
```

The library then can manipulate your dom element and hence your page.

I was just wondering is possible to do something similar with AngularJS?

So I could write a library / application in AngularJS and somebody could embed that in their page without using an iFrame?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible (but it has limitations). E.g. there will be issues if the page itself is using Angular (unless you can ensure that the part of the DOM your library takes control of is outside of the Angular context of the page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146749/embed-angular-app-within-another-page