# What is bet way to embed an angular js app into 3rd party websites?

Tags: angularjs

Want to integrate an angular js app into a 3rd party website. Iframes is one possible solution. Want to know if there is any better way to integrate the angularjs app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed Angular App within another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146749/embed-angular-app-within-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a java script file in the third party application and add a iframe inserting code

```
var finalEmbedCode = "<iframe src=\"https://www.example.com/home/?product=false&config=" + someConfig + "\" \n                                                height=\"" + iframeHeight + " px\"\n                                                 width= \"" + iframeWidth + " px\"\n                                                 frameborder=\"0\"\n                                                 style=\"border: 0;\"></iframe>";

document.getElementById("insert-on-this-id").innerHTML = finalEmbedCode;
```

product and config are query params you may or may not need.

put you above code in a js file and also `"insert-on-this-id"` is a id on html element which either you add through js file or chug from the party party app which in case if you want to use it any website or blog will be hard to find.

Cheers!!